# What is the better way to create an ArrayList for an Android App?

Tags: android, performance, list

I need to have a very big ArrayList in my App (around 400 items) each one with two `Strings` and an `ImageView` from drawable that Inflates a `RecyclerView`

**what is the most performance and memory - friendly approach I can use?**

**Is there something I need to pay attention to, when I use it?**

Comment: As far as I know, you have to store the entire list for a RecyclerView to work... What performance problem are you having?

Comment: I'm not having any problem at all. I just would like to know if there is some better and worst way to do it in terms of performance. And if so, how?

Comment: A worse way would be a ListView without a ViewHolder pattern. I'm not aware of a better way

Comment: I am using `RecyclerView` so I have a `ViewHolder` already set up, I mean even in the code. Is there a sintax I can use to preserve RAM and increase performance or I shouldn't bother about that and let Android handle it for me?

Comment: The code is so straight-forward and minimal for loading data into a RecyclerView, so there isn't anything you can do there. Plus, as I said, the whole list is held in memory, so as long as you do not initialize new instances of any objects, you shouldn't see more RAM usage than what is already used.

Comment: As I said above since I have got a really big list, It could be a problem to handle it for low level devices with 1 or 2 GB of RAM, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think 400 instances of 2 strings and a drawable would reach anywhere near 1 Gb. Though, that depends how large the strings are

Comment: The Strings are quite small actually, so I shouldn't have any problem even on lower end devices